# No email field type on Drupal 8 core

Tags: drupal-8

I am using Drupal 8.x and trying to create a field signup_email using form API where type is email.

```
'#type' => 'email',
```

I read that field type `email` is in core modules but can't find it in the admin modules section.

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In Drupal 8, email fields were moved into the core "Field" module.

As long as the Field module is enabled, you should be able to create email fields. You don't have to enable a separate module for it.